# inotify CREATE notification with fusepy

Tags: python, fuse, inotify

So I have a filesystem that is downloading some data, storing it in memory, and representing only completed downloads as files to the user. 
However, each download may take time to complete, so I don't want the user to have to wait for all the files to finish downloading. The way I do this is by choosing which 'files' to list in readdir.

When I open nautlius to see the files, I only see the first few and have to refresh to see the rest.

When I monitor the inotify activity, I noticed there are no CREATE events for the newly completed downloads. What do I need to do to create this notification?

Answer (score 1):

Inotify is concerned with calls on vfs level only, if you call fuse operations within a fuse filesystem, inotify would not know about this.

Answer (score -1):

You need IN_CLOSE_WRITE. From `inotify` man page:

> IN_CLOSE_WRITE (+)
>
> File opened for writing was closed.

Comment: I tried to generate this notification by calling touch after the file has been loaded, but this didn't trigger a reload for nautilius. I think what I really need is IN_CREATE. Is there anyway to synthetically generate this?

Comment: @AneeshDurg mknod, perhaps? Make sure, that you implement it in your filesystem.